# Docker-The scale command is deprecated. Use the up command with the --scale flag instead

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, devops

i want to launch 5 chrome and 5 firefox in docker container. I am using the below command but its giving the following error
***The scale command is deprecated. Use the up command with the --scale flag instead.
ERROR: No such service: nodechrome***

```
docker-compose scale nodechrome=5 nodefirefox=5
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32772:5900"

  chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32773:5900"

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

Comment: Did you try to use the up command with the scale flag instead?

Answer (score 0):

From where these names came? nodechrome and nodefirefox

Correct your command instead:

from:

```
docker-compose scale nodechrome=5 nodefirefox=5
```

to:

```
docker-compose scale chromenode=5 firefoxnode=5
```

Comment: ERROR: for default_chromenode_4  Cannot start service chromenode: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint default_chromenode_4 (99636809c38ac0e05eb87fe80b02c81dda8613c2cec047c4c6f52de23ffa57f1): Bind for 0.0.0.0:32773 failed: port is already allocated'

Comment: that is a different error that you need to fix , but the service names were wrong in your first command

Comment: ok..WARNING: The scale command is deprecated. Use the up command with the --scale flag instead.
WARNING: The "chromenode" service specifies a port on the host. If multiple containers for this service are created on a single host, the port will clash.

Comment: Yes , you need to use the scaling features on a swram cluster , not on a single node swarm i guess , as i said , these warnings are not related to your origional question error

Comment: you just need to be aware of the ports , not to refuse them in other services , ignore the warnings

Answer (score 0):

**Try this command:**

```
docker-compose up --scale chrome=5
```

Verify the Grid by visiting: http://localhost:4444/ui/index.html#/

Refer: [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)